# Haskell "Parse error in pattern" when deriving an instance from Eq

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I am learning Haskell with the help of "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" and am currently trying to understand typeclasses and instances.
LYAH provides an [example](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-102) where a type called `TrafficLight` is defined as follows:

```
data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green
```

Now `TrafficLight` is supposed to be an instance of `Eq` displaying the following behaviour:

```
instance Eq TrafficLight where
    Red == Red = True
    Green == Green = True
    Yellow == Yellow = True
    _ == _ = False
```

In order to understand how this works, I wrote my own file called `Shop.hs` where I try to override the behaviour of `Eq` for my `ItemSlot`.

```
module Shop where

type Number = Int

data Item =
          BellPepper
        | Cabbage
        | Carrot
        | Lettuce
        | Onion
        | Potato
        | Tomato
        deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

data ItemSlot = ItemSlot {
        item :: Item,
        number :: Number
        } deriving (Show)

instance Eq ItemSlot where
        ((item a) == (item a)) = True -- line that contains the error
        _ == _ = False
```

However, if I load the file in GHCi, I get the following error:

```
Prelude> :l Shop.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Shop             ( Shop.hs, interpreted )

Shop.hs:21:11: Parse error in pattern: item
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

(I must admit that I am rather confused as to what the correct syntax is here - is it `item a` or just `item`?
Using only `item` fails with the same error, and using more parentheses - as was the answer in another question like this on SO - does not seem to help either.)

My guess is that I cannot use the `item` function provided by the record-syntax that is used in `ItemSlot`, but nevertheless I do not know how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patterns typically begin with a constructor. The constructor for the `ItemSlot` type is `ItemSlot`, so you would use that:

```
instance Eq ItemSlot where
    ItemSlot item a == ItemSlot item' a' = -- use item, item', a, and a'
```

Alternately, because you've defined `ItemSlot` as a record, there's so-called record syntax for patterns. You can bind variables by name rather than position:

```
instance Eq ItemSlot where
    ItemSlot { item = foo, number = a } == ItemSlot { item = foo', number = a' }
        = -- use foo, foo', a, and a'
```

You can of course shadow names, if you don't mind a chance of confusion:

```
instance Eq ItemSlot where
    ItemSlot { item = item, number = a } == ItemSlot { item = item', number = a' }
        = -- use item, item', a, and a'
```

For convenience, patterns in Haskell can be nested; so, if you wanted to match `ItemSlot`s that both had `BellPepper`s, for example, you could write

```
instance Eq ItemSlot where
    ItemSlot BellPepper a == ItemSlot BellPepper a' = True
    -- or, equivalently
    ItemSlot { item = BellPepper } == ItemSlot { item = BellPepper } = True
```

though usually you would delegate the comparison of `Item`'s to the `Eq` instance for `Item`s.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your first example does it for me (I only want to compare for the same item, not the same number). I guess I never would have figured that out on my own.

Comment: Just to add to this: you *can* use the `item` accessor function (or any other function) on the *right*-hand side of the definition.  So `instance Eq ItemSlot where is1 == is2 = item is1 == item is2` would also work.  The pattern-matching way is probably better, though.

Comment: @Antal S-Z: That's exactly what I'd originaly thought was the best way, but obviously I got distracted while writing my answer. I've edited my answer but upvoted your comment. Thanks reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching worked in the `TrafficLight` example because you 
only needed to know what the constructor (`Red`, `Green` or `Yellow`) 
was to tell whether they were equal, but your `ItemSlot`s are only 
equal if the *data* in the `item` field is equal, so you need to check 
that with an equation on the right hand side:

```
instance Eq ItemSlot where
        ItemSlot {item=i} == ItemSlot {item=j} = i == j
```

This is the equivalent of

```
instance Eq ItemSlot where
        ItemSlot i _ == ItemSlot j _  =  i == j
```

but is more future proof, because if you add another field and you
don't want to change the meaning of `==`, you can leave the first version 
alone. (You could argue that you ought to revisit `==` when you add fields,
but using the `{item =` syntax leads to clearer error messages in my 
experience.

Cleanest is

```
instance Eq ItemSlot where 
        i == j  =  item i == item j
```

as Antal S-Z reminded me (thanks).

If you test with

```
eg1 = ItemSlot {item = Carrot, number = 3}
eg2 = ItemSlot {item = Onion, number = 3}
eg3 = ItemSlot {item = Onion, number = 42}
eg4 = ItemSlot {item = Carrot, number = undefined}
eg5 = ItemSlot {item = Carrot}
```

You'll find that `eg5` gives you a warning. You're allowed
to ignore fields when using the record, so the first version of `Eq` above is
fine, but if you're defining a record, Haskell would like you to provide all the 
data.

You can check that `eg4 == eg1` and `eg2 == eg4` and even `eg2 == eg5` without 
problems - lazy evaluation means it doesn't check the number field when checking `==`,
but if you just type `eg4` or `eg5`, it won't finish because it encounters the undefined values.